# Trying to create a trigger that only allow updates to record that are less than three days old

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

Am trying to create a trigger that update a record less than three days old
heres my code wen i execute tables blank i think the error is with the dateadd function
any suggestions?

```
 ALTER TRIGGER update_marketinglistC
    ON marketing_list FOR UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN

        SELECT * FROM INSERTED 
        SELECT * FROM DELETED

        Select * from inserted 
        where DateCreated <= DATEADD(dd,-3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)



    END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Alter Trigger update_marketinglistC
On marketing_list For Update
As

Begin

    If exists (Select * from inserted 
               Where DateCreated <= DATEADD(dd, -3, current_Timestamp))
    Begin
        Rollback Transaction
        Raiserror('Cannot update records more than three days old.', 16, 1)
    End

End
```

Comment: code was correct. Thanks still the record i was trying to update wasnt in the table